# Utilizar o diff do laravel em duas collections

Tags: laravel, collection, laravel-collective, coleção

Estou tentando buscar os itens que não estão em um determinado produto.

Possuo, portanto, uma model `Produto`, cada produto tem vários itens, e uma outra model `Item`.

Estou tentando usar *collections* do Laravel, mais especificamente o método `diff`, da seguinte maneira:

```
public function buscarItens($id)
{
    $produto = Produto::find($id);

    //busca todos os itens cadastrados
    $todosItens = Item::all();

    //busca os itens do produto
    $itensDoProduto = $produto->itens;

    //retorna os produtos que NÃO PERTENCEM ao item + os produtos que PERTENCEM ao item
    $collection1 = collect($todosItens);
    $diff = $collection1->diff($itensDoProduto);

    return response()->json($collection1);
}
```

Acontece que essa diferença que está retornando é igual ao próprio `$todosItens`, como se não houvesse nenhum item em comum entre o `$itensDoProduto` e `$todosItens`, mas existe.

O que pode estar acontecendo?

<sub>**OBS**: Pensei em usar o `diffKeys()`, mas quero buscar apenas a diferença de `ids`, e não de todos os atributos.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## Qual é a `Collection` certa?

Você precisa entender que existe a diferença entre as classes `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` e `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. A primeira é retornada quando você chama o `get` em uma consulta feita pelo `Eloquent`, a segunda, porém, quando você chama a função `collect`.

O `diff` dessas duas classes funcionam de maneiras distintas!

Observe a diferença entre a definição do [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php#L173) e [Illuminate\Support\Collection](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L301).

Logo, você deverá optar por usar o `Collection` do `Eloquent` e não do `Support`.

Assim:

```
public function buscarItens($id)
{
    $produto = Produto::find($id);

    $todosItens = Item::all();

    $diff = $todosItens->diff($produto->itens);

    return response()->json($diff);
}
```

<sub>**Nota**: Dei uma limpada nas definições, pois não é necessário sair declarando tantas variáveis que mal são utilizadas.</sub>

## Preste atenção no código!

Outro detalhe é que você quer retornar a diferença, porém está retornando a variável `$collection1`, que representa "todos os itens". Isso está parecendo uma falha sua na hora de escrever o código.

## Por quê não retornar direto da consulta?

Você pode retornar resultados baseados em relacionamentos através das consultas do `Eloquent`. Existem quatro métodos que costumo usar muito para isso: `whereHas`, `has`, `doesntHave`, `whereDoesntHave`.

Por exemplo, se eu quero retornar todos os itens que não têm relacionamentos com o `Produto` de id `1`, eu posso usar `whereDoesntHave`.

```
$itensNaoRelacionados = Item::whereDoesntHave('produto', function ($query) use ($id) {
                                $query->where('id', '=', $id);
                            })->get();
```